# Error while getting current location in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to get the current location in my flutter application, the app is executing but later on the mobile screen its throwing me an error like nosuchmethoderror and also on my terminal its throwing me an error.can someone please help me in this.

Here's my Code:

```
class LocationService {
  // Keep track of current Location
  UserLocation _currentLocation;
  Location location = Location();
  // Continuously emit location updates
  StreamController<UserLocation> _locationController =
      StreamController<UserLocation>.broadcast();

  LocationService() {
    location.requestPermission().then((granted) {
      if (granted) {
        location.onLocationChanged().listen((locationData) {
          if (locationData != null) {
            _locationController.add(UserLocation(
              latitude: locationData.latitude,
              longitude: locationData.longitude,
            ));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<UserLocation> get locationStream => _locationController.stream;

  Future<UserLocation> getLocation() async {
    try {
      var userLocation = await location.getLocation();
      _currentLocation = UserLocation(
        latitude: userLocation.latitude,
        longitude: userLocation.longitude,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Could not get the location: $e');
    }

    return _currentLocation;
  }
}
```

Here's my error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27476): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomeView(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter (27476): [InheritedProvider<UserLocation>]):
I/flutter (27476): The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
I/flutter (27476): Receiver: null
I/flutter (27476): Tried calling: latitude
I/flutter (27476): 
I/flutter (27476): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (27476):   HomeView
I/flutter (27476):   file:///C:/Users/GANGADHAR%20YADAV/AndroidStudioProjects/027-location-service/lib/main.dart:16:57
I/flutter (27476): 
I/flutter (27476): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (27476): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
I/flutter (27476): #1      HomeView.build (package:location_service/views/home_view.dart:14:43)
I/flutter (27476): #2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4291:28)
I/flutter (27476): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
I/flutter (27476): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (27476): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter (27476): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
I/flutter (27476): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (27476): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
I/flutter (27476): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
I/flutter (27476): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
I/flutter (27476): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
```

Main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserLocation>(
        builder: (context) => LocationService().locationStream,
        child: MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', home: HomeView()));
  }
}
```

Userlocation.dart

```
class UserLocation {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;

  UserLocation({this.latitude, this.longitude});
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that

Comment: Can you please show your `HomeView` code?

Comment: i have updated my codes kindly please check

Comment: This was because your latitude is getting null value to try to put breakpoint or in debug mode and let me know where you getting null latitude

Comment: can you tell me where can i add a breakpoint

Comment: First of all user location and location then in your condition then after latitude and longitude note that you are getting location or not and also after checking location check your latitude and longitude

Comment: add initialData to your StreamProvider in order to expose some value until the Stream emits a value. If omitted, defaults to null. Hence the null pointer exception

Comment: @myname also, try this library very easy to use https://pub.dev/packages/location

Comment: can someone please modify my code and give please because i'm not undertanding how its done

Comment: sir basically i want the current location in my food delivering app

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "()" from onLocationChanged . I hope it will remove the error. Refer to Location package documentations.